# Understanding this analog circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog

The circuit below is from a really old device, however I'm trying to understand it. As far as I can see, the comparator U2 is working as multivibrator or astable oscillator, and this circuit works as long as PB1 is pressed. I think the purpose is to cause an AC current through the test coil. When PB1 is pressed and M2 is ON a current flows in one direction through the coil and while PB1 is ON and M2 is OFF the current reverses direction, am I right?

I'd appreciate any guidance.

[image]

Comment: what device is that from?

Comment: It would help us to know the function of the device you found this in.

Comment: It was in an old ground fault relay. PB1 is the test button which causes the relay to trip purposely.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a tester for large coils in the 5H range to resonate at 50 Hz or so near Q=1 according to my RLC nomograph.   What did you want to know?